# Thinking about this word gave me a headache!

Tags: riddle, word

I am an **8-letter word**. I have a special property that can be a headache for many scholars. Every day, I lose a letter and subsequently rearrange myself into a meaningful word.

Based on the hints provided below, guess the word on **Day 0**.

1. *On Day 1*, I am what dreamers do.
2. *On Day 2*, No one can understand me.
3. *On Day 3*, I finally get imprinted in everyone's memory.
4. *On Day 4*, Everyone loves me, or at least some types of me.
5. *On Day 5*, I realise I can only ever increase, and cannot be fought.

Comment: Great puzzle. Is it considered cheating that I figured out the answer from the title of the post and subsequent hint in the wording? Then having guessed the answer, followed it through to prove it worked for all days. Maybe consider making hints a little less heavy handed?

Comment: In hindsight, i do agree. I always knew it was a simple puzzle, but maybe it was too trivial. I'm new to the site and still figuring out the optimal level of puzzles. Thanks for the compliment, and the feedback :)

Comment: Good puzzle, and I don't mind that it's not super-hard. In fact, that makes a refreshing change - I could actually solve about half of it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer:

> The answer is MIGRAINE. (hinted by "headache")
> Dreamers IMAGINE.
> An ENIGMA is hard to understand.
> An IMAGE gets imprinted in your memory.
> Everyone loves a GAME of sorts. (right?)
> And AGE only increases and cannot be fought.

This was short and sweet, and I quite like it.

Comment: Bravo! Well done!