# Someone help me heal my wounds

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, story

> Every day, I is making such gud puzzles but received no attention. My friends is laugh at me and make things more bad. I feel wounded. My younger sister telling to me that I need something. That something is such long word I not understand so she gives me a puzzle to find it. I not able to solve puzzle, pliz help.*

---

The word in question follows a special rule. Every day, it loses a letter and may subsequently rearrange itself to form a meaningful word again.

> eg: `STOP` may become `POT`, `TOP`, `SOT`, etc., on the next day.
> <sub>(Note that rearrangement is optional, and the word so formed must be meaningful.)</sub>

For the given word, the words formed after *n* days can be deciphered from the hints below:

1. Not a state secret, but still confidential.
2. Becomes chaotic when unplanned.
3. Found in New York, but not anymore.
4. He's been lost without a trace.
5. This is a site for those who create, solve and study puzzles.
6. Nothing goes unnoticed here.
7. Best to wear this in a fight.

---

Hint:

> The original word (i.e., on Day 0) is **9 letters long**.

---

<sub>*Fictional</sub>

Comment: Does n=1 for "Not a state secret, but still confidential", etc?  Or are these clues a non-ordered list?

Comment: They are in order. The serial number indicates *n* days have elapsed.

Comment: are all the days hints referring to single words?  are any of them proper nouns or multiple words?

Comment: Yes, each day's hint refers to a single word, none of them are multiple words.  Each word is a dictionary word, but the hints may be using them as a proper noun. As an example, a hint may say '007' with the word being *Bond*, which is also a noun and a verb in the dictionary.

Comment: The rot13(ynfg jbeq vf gjb yrggref) according to the hint. Would it still be following the rules if the word was rot13(purzvpny ryrzrag)

Comment: Hmm, interesting thought. But no, unfortunately, that's not the right track.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need

> DESALTING
>  <sub>(You are wounded and the friends 'make it worse', i.e., they *rub salt into your wounds*)</sub>

1. Not a state secret, but still confidential.

> GENITALS (keep these private!)

2. Becomes chaotic when unplanned.

> SEATING (at a wedding when you've invited exes)

3. Found in New York, but not anymore.

> GIANTS (American Football team whose stadium is in New Jersey)

4. He's been lost without a trace.

> STING (of The Police (band), who is "lost without a trace" in the song "Ev'ry Breath You Take")

5. This is a site for those who create, solve and study puzzles.

> GIST

6. Nothing goes unnoticed here.

> GIT (because I can see your pull requests?)

7. Best to wear this in a fight.

> GI (martial arts uniform)

Comment: gnatvoyrf? (orggre chmmyrf) qrfnygvat? (ybir naq pner) erfyngvat? (n arj crefcrpgvir)

Comment: Woohooo! You got everything but day 0 right! @Amoz is right about rot13(Qrfnygvat. Ur fnlf ur vf jbhaqrq. Uvf sevraqf znxr sha bs uvz gb znxr guvatf jbefr, v. r., gurl eho fnyg va uvf jbhaqf. Uvf jbhaqf arrq qrfnygvat :c)

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind Day 5?

Comment: @Sid the day 5 statement is the gist of what this site is for.

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora but doesn't that mean the puzzle has no clear solution? Another could be that the friends were acting rot13(grnfvatyl). Is there a clue to the 'correct' answer that indicates a particular answer, and not one that could be better or worse, or the one you thought of (so it is guess-work)? Please see [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6715/about-non-open-ended-puzzles-with-multiple-answers-working-towards-an-optimum) about open-ended puzzles. No 5 is a particularly 'thin' clue, too, and no 6 eludes me completely.

Comment: I don't think it's an open-ended puzzle. Your suggestion, rot13(grnfvatyl) doesn't make sense as the word has to be something that the protagonist needs. Please see my [reasoning](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110496/someone-help-me-heal-my-wounds/110541?noredirect=1#comment310714_110541) as to why I feel rot13(qrfnygvat) is the 'correct' answer.

Comment: In riddles and such word-based puzzles, it is often the case that you cannot 'prove' a particular answer, which means interpretations may vary and you may get a lot of decent answers, as is the case [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110415/this-word-chain-will-come-back-to-me/110438), which is good, but there must be one answer which stands out as the most appropriate, and hence deemed as 'correct', according to the parameters of the question. I may be wrong, but I do believe that is the case here as well.

Comment: As far as the clue for day 5 being particularly *thin* goes, I do agree. The last time I made a similar puzzle, it was [suggested](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110426/thinking-about-this-word-gave-me-a-headache#comment310294_110426) that I keep the hints *a little less heavy handed*, which is what I tried to do. Maybe I need to find a middle ground :)

Comment: The explanation for day 6 is that rot13(tvg (n irefvba pbageby flfgrz) nyybjf lbh gb pbzcerurafviryl genpx nyy punatrf znqr gb gur pbqr, jub jebgr n cnegvphyne yvar bs pbqr, jura vg jnf jevggra naq gur ragver erivfvba uvfgbel. Rirelguvat vf ninvynoyr sbe cbfgrevgl, hfhnyyl. Urapr, *abguvat tbrf haabgvprq urer*.)

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora thank you, I did enjoy tackling the puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the word is

> NEGATIVES (v) meaning to contradict and has synonyms deny and neutralize.  In other words, fight back!

Day 1

> VINTAGES - one's vintage (or age) is certainly confidential, though hardly a state secret

Day 2

> STAVING - one meaning is to create a hole in a ships hull.  If this was unplanned, chaos is a very real possibility (c.f. Titanic).

Day 3

> GIANTS - the New York Giants (football) in New Jersey AND the San Francisco Giants (baseball) both moved away from New York. This means that, indeed, there are no more giants (sports-wise at least) in New York (thanks @shoover for word)

Day 4

> STING - as @shoover points out, Sting (the Police) wrote/sang "I've been lost without a trace" in "Every Breath You Take".

Day 5

> GIST, TIGS, TING - none of these seem to fit. The closest I see is tigs.in, which has some puzzles but they are not the purpose of the site.

Day 6

> TIG - the definition of which is a "noticeable (but not violent) touch".

Day 7

> GI - a garment worn for martial arts exhibitions.  I suppose if you wore martial arts clothing, you may have advantage in a fight.

Comment: Is there a slight mis-count? Day 0 = 8, Day 1 = 7, Day 2 = 7 ...

Comment: @WeatherVane oops left the S off 0 and 1.  probably because i liked it better without!.  Fixed now, for what its worth

Answer (score 1):

Most of the puzzle was [solved](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/110541/51581), but I offer two solutions for the title word, relevant to:

> **Someone help me heal my wounds**
> My younger sister telling to me that I need something. That something is such long word I not understand so she gives me a puzzle to find it.

> **Alginates**
>  [Alginates are medications that work through an alternative mechanism, by displacing the postprandial gastric acid pocket](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6836317/)

or

> **Splintage**
>  [Splintage in the treatment of sagittal band incompetence and extensor tendon subluxation](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24729035/)

These two can both lose one letter to become the 1st day's word, as answered:

> **Genitals**